# copy from child node to parent

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this structure

```
<a href="xxx" class="box">
  <img src="1.jpg" alt="CBA" title="ABC" class="imgresp" height="204" width="307">
</a>
```

What I want:
If an A-tag has class "box"
then copy the title attribute from img to parent A-tag

Expected output:

```
<a href="xxx" class="box" title="ABC">
  <img src="1.jpg" alt="CBA" title="ABC" class="imgresp" height="204" width="307">
</a>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect, please? Also, if you have tried some XSLT already, can you also show that, even if it doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: updated with desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the XML needs to be well-formed, so the `img` tag needs to be closed, otherwise it won't be possible to use XSLT on it.

```
<a href="xxx" class="box">
  <img src="1.jpg" alt="CBA" title="ABC" class="imgresp" height="204" width="307" />
</a>
```

Assuming that is really the case, you then need read up on the X[SLT identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On it's own, it just copies all the nodes and attributes from the input XML to the output XML as-is, which in your case, brings you 99% of the way there.

Then, all you need is a template to copy the extra attribute you need. In this case, you need a template that matches the `a` tag, which copies it, but adds the extra attribute on too.

```
<xsl:template match="a[@class='box']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="img/@title" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe, like this, using [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to create the attribute

```
<xsl:template match="a[@class='box']">
    <a title="{img/@title}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[@class='box']">
        <a title="{img/@title}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a template that matches the nodes 'a' and 'img' and their attributes. This template copies the nodes, do a test if there is an attributes 'class' in order to add the title attributes

```
  <xsl:template match="a/@* |img/@* | a | img">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="@class = 'box' ">
          <xsl:attribute name="title" select="img/@title"/>
        </xsl:if>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```